# TCL: A variable stores a floating point value, how can this be printed on screen as a hex?

Tags: floating-point, hex, tcl, data-conversion

How do I store the hex representation of a floating point number in tcl:

```
% set a 1.3
1.3
% puts $a
1.3
```

I want to store the hex representation inside another variable and then print it on screen or use it for other purposes.

Comment: Please take some time to read [this help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I store the hex representation of a floating point number in
>   Tcl:

A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58935990/tcl-a-variable-stores-a-hex-value-that-represents-a-floating-point-number-how) of yours has been answered already, and should point you into the right direction: Turn the given float into a 32-bit integer (this is called the IEEE 754 binary32 representation), then turn this binary32 representation into its hexadecimal form. In Tcl (8.6+), for example, you can achieve this via:

```
% set a 1.3
1.3
% set ahex [binary encode hex [binary format f $a]]; # hex will be in big-endian form!
6666a63f
```

Following the previous answer, you can reverse the operation using:

```
% binary scan [binary format i 0x$ahex] R x
1
% set x
1.2999999523162842
```

Mind the use of the `R` specifier (big endian) to `binary scan`, rather than `f` (little or big, platform-dependent), because the hex produced is in big-endian form. Generally, you have to pay attention to the endianness in binary32 conversions.

Comment: The ahex from the first part does not start with 0x, the hex value is without 0x. How do I add 0x? I have tried set ahex "0x" [binary encode hex [binary format f $a]]; but this does not work.

Comment: Use: `set ahex "0x[binary encode ...]"`, you should make sure that you have Tcl basics covered ([string concatenation](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+Tutorial+Lesson+3)).